# Conversion to logical from gpuArray is not possible

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

when I use gpu to run this project in matlab

```
 function y = relu(x)
      if x>0
      y=x;
      else
      y=0.1*x;
      end
```

the error is Conversion to logical from gpuArray is not possible
Error in relu (line 5)
  if x>0
while the type of x is 4-D gpuArray.
how to solve this problem,thanks...

Comment: also, I have no idea what you are doing, but your code works only if `x` is 1x1 in size. And really, its a terrible idea to have a 1x1 gpuArray. did you meant `y(x>0)=x(x>0); y(x<0)=0.01*x(x<0)`? because the first if will be true if any of them is true.

Comment: Hi, please consider accepting one of the answers below. Although it's not mandatory, it's a nice gesture to those who have tried to help you. It will also make the question appear solved to anyone who might have a similar question in the future. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the Parallel Computing Toolbox, so I'll provide you with an example that *should* work, according to the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html):

The `gt` operation is implemented for gpuArray elements, so this *should* work:

```
function y = relu(x)
if gt(x,0)
    y=x;
else
    y=0.1*x;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, MATLAB doesn't know how to convert a non-scalar `gpuArray` into a scalar `logical` to control the `if` statement. It does know how to convert scalars, so you should do simply

```
if all(x > 0)
    ...
end
```